# One question on boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ closed unbounded operator, and $S\neq 0$, nor multiple of $I$ is bounded operator. If $TS=ST$, then is it true $TS$ is unbounded? If not, please give counterexample. Furthermore, under what condition on $S$, we always have $TS$ is bounded. More precisely, what is the necessary condition to have $TS$ is bounded? For instance, what can happen for $S$ unitary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, $TS$ can but does not need to be unbounded.

Take for instance the sequence space $\ell^2$ as a Hilbert space with basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, so $ f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n e_n $ for all $ f \in l^2 $. Define the operator $T$ by
$$T e_n = n\; e_n$$

This operator is unbounded and you may define it in a closed (even self-adjoint) way on the domain
$$ \mathrm{dom}(T) = \left\{f: \sum_{n=1}^\infty |n \; f_n|^2 < \infty \right\}$$

Now, the operator $S_1:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ defined by
$$ S_1 e_n = \frac{1}{n} e_n $$
is bounded by $\Vert S_1 \Vert = 1 $ and it holds that $ T S_1 = S_1 T = 1 $. So in particular, $ TS_1 $ is bounded.

However, if you define $ S_2:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ by
$$ S_1 e_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \; e_n, $$
then still $\Vert S_1 \Vert = 1$ (so it is bounded) and $ TS_2 = S_2 T $. But $ TS_2$ acts by
$$TS_2 e_n = \sqrt{n} e_n,$$

So it is unbounded.

That means, both bounded and unbounded $TS$ are possible.

Finding a necessary condition for the boundedness is in general not that easy. However, it helps a lot, if $T$ and $S$ are normal on some Hilbert space $ \mathcal{H} $, i.e. $T^*T = TT^*$ and $S^*S = SS^*$. This is in particular the case if $S$ and $T$ are either unitary ($SS^* = 1$) of self-adjoint ($S = S^*$). In that case, you can apply the spectral theorem, i.e. there exists some subset $ \sigma \subset \mathbb{C} $, called spectrum, such that $ S $ and $T$ can be represented by multiplications with some functions $ s(\lambda), t(\lambda) $ with $  \lambda \in \sigma $.

(To be more precise, there is some $ X \subset \mathbb{N} $ and some unitary operator $ U: \mathcal{H} \to L^2(\sigma \times X) $, such that $ USU^* $ is a multiplication by a function $ s: \sigma \times X \to \mathbb{C} $ such that $ s(\lambda,x) $ only depends on $ \lambda $, so we may also call it $ s(\lambda) $. And the same for $T$)

The necessary and sufficient condition in that case is that the product function
$$ \lambda \mapsto s(\lambda) t(\lambda) $$
is bounded on $ \lambda \in \sigma $. So there is a maximal factor, by which the product $ TS = ST $ can multiply.

Comment: Could you answer the last part of the question @Sascha?

Comment: Alright, I tried to answer the last question as good as I can. Spectral theory provides an answer in a slightly simplified case, which does often appear in mathematics. The generic case is probably more difficult.